# Django - Match objects by properties

Tags: django, python-3.x, matching

I have three models:

```
class Skill(model):
    skill = CharField()

class Person(Model):
    skills = ManyToManyField(Skill)

class Job(Model):
    skills = ManyToManyField(Skill)
```

I want to match all jobs with a certain skill set, to candidates with an identical or also similar skill set.

How is this usually done? From what I can see, Django does not provide any on-board means.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide some codes you have done

Comment: There is no code to provide, as I am seeking an approach not a concrete solution. More like a point in a certain direction.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
person = Person.objects.first()
Job.objects.filter(skills__in=person.skills.all())
```

Or with [**`reverse relation`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/) between `Skill` to `Person` model:

```
Job.objects.filter(skills__person__pk=1)  # where primary key of the person object is 1
```

Comment: This is kind of what I am looking for, however with some sort of ranking and weighted results.

Comment: You need to store rank and weight information somewhere in the model. If you can share that, maybe we can help.